# EF 5 (Code First) AddOrUpdate duplicates nested data

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have these simple entities:

```
public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding data in the seed method like this:

```
var parent = new Parent { Name = "First" };

context.Parents.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, parent);

var children = new[]{
    new Child { Parent = parent, Name = "Child1" },
    new Child { Parent = parent, Name = "Child2" },
};

context.Children.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Name, children);
```

This works as expected and I can update the database (update-database) multiple times - no duplicates. However if I add a third child like this:

```
var parent = new Parent { Name = "First" };

context.Parents.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, parent);

var children = new[]{
    new Child { Parent = parent, Name = "Child1" },
    new Child { Parent = parent, Name = "Child2" },
    new Child { Parent = parent, Name = "Child3" },
};

context.Children.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Name, children);
```

and invoke update-database **again** a second parent is inserted and now I have two of them in the database. If I need a fourth child and add it a third parent will be inserted and so on.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How/where/when do you exactly add `Child3`? In a second run? The same run, after the first two? Is the `new Parent` statement repeated?

Comment: I add Child 3 in a second run.

Comment: Why are you adding these in separate runs? And if you use the debugger to check the `parent` variable in the second run (after the `AddOrUpdate`), is it already a different entity/row to the first run's `parent`?

Comment: This is not the issue. I have removed the duplicate code so now I am invoking AddOrUpdate only once. However the issue still persists.